# How to check current MERGE_THRESHOLD value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, innodb

There is a new variable that we can set in creating a table / Index which is **MERGE_THRESHOLD**.

the description of which is here:
[Merge threshold for innodb index pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-page-merge-threshold.html)

But how to check the current value of merge_threshold ?

I used this query like we check for other variables but didn't succeed.

> show variables like 'MERGE_THRESHOLD' ;

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found on the MySQL documentation that you [linked in your question](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-page-merge-threshold.html):

> The current MERGE_THRESHOLD value for an index can be obtained by
>   querying the INNODB_SYS_INDEXES table. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_INDEXES WHERE
> NAME='id_index' \G
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>        INDEX_ID: 91
>            NAME: id_index
>        TABLE_ID: 68
>            TYPE: 0
>        N_FIELDS: 1
>         PAGE_NO: 4
>           SPACE: 57
> MERGE_THRESHOLD: 40
> ```
>
> You can use SHOW CREATE TABLE to view the MERGE_THRESHOLD value for a
>   table, if explicitly defined using the table_option COMMENT clause:
>
> ```
> mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE t2 \G
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>        Table: t2 Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t2` (   `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   KEY `id_index` (`id`) COMMENT 'MERGE_THRESHOLD=40' )
> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```